# Как передать данные в динамически созданные UIView(xib) Version 10.3, Swift 5

Tags: swift, дата, view, динамическое-программирование, xib

***Добрый день, не могли бы мне подсказать, как я могу передать текст в созданный мной UIView(xib)?***
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Дело в том что я имею массив **type = ["CheckBox","Data","TextField",...,"ComboBox"]**
По идеи количество и сами объекты могут быть **рандомные**.
***Моя задача в зависимости от названия объектов в массиве их динамически создать. И после этого выполнить с ними обычные операции.***
ComboBox - сделать выпадающий список, CheckBox - что бы она работала и т.д.
Для удобства я решил создать эти объекты отдельно в виде xib файлов.

Все шло хорошо пока я не столкнулся с некоторыми трудностями. А именно..
Я создал View "DataTime" он содержит в себе кнопку(UIButton) "Дата".[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
При нажатии на нее в середине UIVIewController()должен появится календарь(он работает). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам календарь тоже отдельный объект UIVIew(xib) и на нем есть кнопка (UIButton) "Выбрать". При нажатии на эту кнопку "Выбрать", дата должна сохраниться как заголовок кнопка "Дата" в классе DataTime. Вызов календаря осуществляется с помощи вызова ее из UIViewController. После выбора даты, кнопка "Выбрать" запускает @objc func в UIViewController ... и тут **проблема, как выбронную дату установить в заголовок кнопки "Дата"**, так как я не знаю как это делать..=\ Буду благодарен за любую помощь)

### Еще добавлю что объекты могут быть рандомные, то есть может прийти как 2, 4 или вообщем не прийти объект в массиве. И все значение с объектов сохраняются в отдельный массив под название arrayText[n]

Я прикреплю ссылку на проект:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kkzeDmeAIFppZIIxj_vtIvbaPhKNMiSY

.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
//UIViewController
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var mainWindowView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var stackViewConstant:  NSLayoutConstraint!      //Ограничение
    @IBOutlet weak var windowStackView: UIStackView!                //StackView:
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonView: UIButton!                        //Button:
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!                             //Label:
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!                             //Label:
    @IBOutlet weak var lineView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewWhite: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ViewConstant:  NSLayoutConstraint!           //Ограничение
    var type = ["ComboBox","CheckBox","ComboBox","DataPicker","TextField"] //Типа динамические объекты по идеи я не знаю что в какой последовательности должно прийти
    var arrayText: [Int: String] = [:]                              //Array empty
    var arrayBool: [Int: String] = [:]                              //Для того что бы понять увеличить comboBox
    var dataBool: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addDynamicsObject()
    }
    
    func addDynamicsObject(){
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.spacing = 5
        viewWhite.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWhite.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWhite.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWhite.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewWhite.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        for i in 0..<5{
            //ComboBox
            if(type[i] == "ComboBox"){
                ViewConstant.constant = ViewConstant.constant + 40
                let comboBox = TestView()
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(comboBox)
                comboBox.textLabel.text = "Amazon"
                comboBox.xibButton.tag = Int(i)
                print("comboBox.tag:", comboBox.xibButton.tag)
                self.arrayText[i] = "false"
                comboBox.xibButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(comboBox(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                comboBox.twoWindowsConstant.constant = 0
                comboBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            }
            
            //CheckBox
            if(type[i] == "CheckBox"){
                ViewConstant.constant = ViewConstant.constant + 40
                let checkBox = CheckBox()
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(checkBox)
                checkBox.checkBoxText.text = "Купить пиццу"
                checkBox.checkBoxButtonOutlet.tag = Int(i)
                self.arrayText[i] = "true"
                checkBox.checkBoxButtonOutlet.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkBox(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
                checkBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            }
            
            //TextField
            if(type[i] == "TextField"){
                ViewConstant.constant = ViewConstant.constant + 40
                let textField = TextFieldView()
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(textField)
                textField.textField.tag = Int(i)
                self.arrayText[i] = ""
                textField.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
                textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            }
            
            //DataPicker
            if(type[i] == "DataPicker"){
                ViewConstant.constant = ViewConstant.constant + 40
                let dataTime = DataTime()
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(dataTime)
                dataTime.dataButton.tag = Int(i)
                self.arrayText[i] = ""
                dataTime.dataButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getData(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
                dataTime.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    //comboBox создаю пространство для comboBox
    @objc func comboBox(sender: UIButton){
        let S = sender.tag
        arrayText[S] = sender.titleLabel!.text!
        if(arrayBool[S] != "true"){
            ViewConstant.constant = ViewConstant.constant + 200
            arrayBool[S] = "true"
        }else{
            ViewConstant.constant = ViewConstant.constant - 200
            arrayBool[S] = "false"
        }
    }
    
    //checkBox создаю пространство ...
    @objc func checkBox(sender: UIButton){
        let S = sender.tag
        arrayText[S] = sender.titleLabel!.text!
        if(arrayText[S] != "false"){
            arrayText[S] = "false"
            print("arrayText[\(S)]):\(String(describing: arrayText[S]))")
        }else{
            arrayText[S] = "true"
            print("arrayText[\(S)]):\(String(describing: arrayText[S]))")
        }
    }
    
    //textField получаю текст из textField и записываю в массив
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        let S = textField.tag
        arrayText[S] = textField.text!
    }
    
    //Создаю календрарь в центре экрана
    @objc func getData(sender: UIButton){
        print("PING")
        let myCalendar = MyDataView()
        self.view.addSubview(myCalendar)
        myCalendar.frame.size = CGSize(width: 250, height: 200)
        myCalendar.center = self.view.center
        myCalendar.myDataButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clickCalendarButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    //touchUpInside myCalendar.myDataButton
    @objc func clickCalendarButton(sender: UIButton){
        print("Дата выбрана:", sender.titleLabel?.text as Any)
    }
}
```

```html
//DataTime
import UIKit

class DataTime: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var childView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dataButton: UIButton!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DataTime", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(mainView)
        mainView.frame = self.bounds
        mainView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
}
```

```html
 //MyCalendar
import UIKit
class MyDataView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var mainMyDataView: UIView!            //Контейнер View
    @IBOutlet weak var myDataButton: UIButton!       //Кнопка "Выбрать"
    @IBOutlet weak var dataPickerSelf: UIDatePicker! //Сам DataPicker
    @IBOutlet weak var dataLabel: UILabel!           //Текстовое поле
    
    //Обработка нажатия кнопки "Выбрать"
    @IBAction func myDataButton(_ sender: Any) {
        myDataButton.titleLabel?.text = formattedData
        self.removeFromSuperview()                      //закрываю календарь
    }
 
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    //Выбор даты
    var formattedData: String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.YYYY"
        let myData = formatter.string(from: dataPickerSelf.date)
        return myData
    }
    
    private func commonInit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyDataView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(mainMyDataView)
        mainMyDataView.frame = self.bounds
        mainMyDataView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае можно было бы использовать Делегаты. Если вы не знакомы с этим подходом - советую ознакомиться.

Причина, почему вы не можете выставить дату кнопке в классе `DataTime` потому что вы не держите на него явно ссылку в классе который вызывает `MyDataView`. Перенесите работу с `MyDataView` в `DataTime`, или храните явно ссылку на `DataTime` в `ViewController` чтобы в методе `clickCalendarButton` выставить `dataTime.dataButton.titleLabel?.text = ...`